# JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ''' is found at position 1. in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an array from the server like this:

```
["Sports", "Life"]
```

and SQL Server is throwing an error like :

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ''' is found at position 1"

My code:

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100) = ["Sport","Life"]

SELECT *
FROM skills
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OPENJSON(@data, '$') AS j
              WHERE skills.description LIKE '%' + j.value + '%')
```

Comment: Post the *actual* code `DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100) = ["Sport","Life"]` itself is invalid and throws `Invalid column name '"Sport","Life"'`

Comment: You'll get this error from `DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100) = ' "Sport","Life"'` for example. Please, check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is set wrong:

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100) = ["Sport","Life"]
```

should be

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100) = '["Sport","Life"]'
```